# Measuring the response time between tasks

Tags: python

I'm coding an program (in Python) that returns me some data.
I want to know how measure the response time between the request and the answer (for performance analysis), then I'll store this in somewhere.

There's a better and efficient way to do this or just inserting for example a `time.ctime()` before the request and another `time.ctime()` after the answer, then subtract them? Like:

```
pre_time = time.ctime()
a = x + y
print a
pos_time = time.ctime()
result_time = postime - pretime
```

Of course this subtraction won't work, but it's just for reference.
Thanks!

Comment: [Timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) Maybe this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easiest solution would be to write a decorator that does the same.

```
import time

def compute_time(func):
     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
         start = time.time()
         result = func(*args, **kwargs)
         time_taken = time.time() - start

         print("Function {0}: {1} seconds".format(func.func_name, time_taken)) 
         # Or you can place a logger here too.

         return result

     return wrapper

@compute_time
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

With that said, if your use case is complex - consider some tailor-made solution like [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html).