# Python: How can i convert this into a decorator

Tags: python, performance, time

I cant't for the life of me figure out how to make this into a decorator.
Any help or an example would be awesome.

**Here is the code**

```
import datetime    

def time_func(function, *args, **kwargs):
  '''
  Add the execution time to a functions attributes 
  '''
  # Start the clock.
  start = datetime.datetime.now()
  # Execute the function and record the results.
  function_result = function(*args, **kwargs)
  # Calculate the elapsed time and add it to the function
  # attributes.
  function.elapsed = datetime.datetime.now() - start
  # Returned the function with the added elapsed attribute 
  return function_result
```

**Here is an example use**

```
.. import datetime 
..  
..  
.. def time_func(function, *args, **kwargs): 
..   ''' 
..   Add the execution time to a functions attributes  
..   ''' 
..   # Start the clock. 
..   start = datetime.datetime.now() 
..   # Execute the function and record the results. 
..   function_result = function(*args, **kwargs) 
..   # Calculate the elapsed time and add it to the function 
..   # attributes. 
..   function.elapsed = datetime.datetime.now() - start 
..   # Returned the function with the added elapsed attribute  
..   return function_result 
..    
..  
.. def f(name): 
..   print name 
..    
.. time_func(f, 'foo') 
.. print f.elapsed 
.. 
foo
0:00:00.000115
```

Comment: check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44846831/6655211)

Comment: have you thought about using the `timeit` module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A decorator is simply a function that takes a function and returns a function.

```
import datetime

def time_func(function):
    # create a new function based on the existing one,
    # that includes the new timing behaviour
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
        # Start the clock.
        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        # Execute the function and record the results.
        function_result = function(*args, **kwargs)
        # Calculate the elapsed time and add it to the function
        # attributes.
        new_func.elapsed = datetime.datetime.now() - start
        # Returned the function with the added elapsed attribute 
        return function_result
    return new_func
```

Usage:

```
@time_func
def f(name):
    print(name)

f('foo')
print(f.elapsed)
> foo
> 0:00:00.000045
```

Check out [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) to further improve the decorator.

Answer (score 2):

Define an inner function:

```
import datetime    

def time_func(function):
    '''
    Add the execution time to a functions attributes 
    '''
    def func(*args, **kwargs):
        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        function_result = function(*args, **kwargs)
        func.elapsed = datetime.datetime.now() - start
        return function_result
    return func

@time_func
def f(name):
    print name
```

Answer (score 0):

A common way to make decorators is to use two nested functions:

```
def time_func(function):
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      start = datetime.datetime.now()
      function_result = function(*args, **kwargs)
      wrapper.elapsed = datetime.datetime.now() - start
      return function_result
   return wrapper
```

The only major between this code and your original (other than stripping out the comments for space) is that the `function` is supplied by a call to the outer function while the other arguments are supplied to the wrapper function. We also need to save the `elapsed` time on the `wrapper` function instead of the original function (since the original will not be accessible any more when you a decorator).

Comment: This doesn't work since `function.elapsed` saves the result to the old function instead of the wrapped one. Instead, use `wrapper.elapsed`.